# How to replace a single line in .sh with Java?

Tags: java

I have a .sh script with a `property=value`. Let it be:

> some_property="some value"

The value of the property is used along the script and script is launched in Java code. I want to dynamically change this property's value. I tried to use `replaceFirst()` method, but I don't know the actual value of "some_property" to replace it correctly using regexp.

How can I edit a .sh file with replacing a single line that starts with `"some_property="` by `some_property=my_value`? By the way there're several places in a file where pattern "some_property=" can be met, so I need to change the first occurrence.

Comment: Unclear: Do you want the Java code to edit the .sh file, or do you want to invoke Java within the .sh file and have it return your "some value" value?

Comment: If you don't know the name, you need to know something about it to be able to replace it. Do you want to replace the first property in the file or the first empty property?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know the name of the property, but I don't know its actual value. In fact I don't need to know its value because I want to replace it with a new one.

Comment: @Dragon In that case, Gustav's suggestion should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be fine with a regex:

```
line.replaceFirst("some_property=.*$", "some_property=\"" + your_value + "\"");
```

Comment: It didn't work at the beginning, but I changed to:
line.replaceFirst("some_property=.*\n", "some_property=\"" + your_value + "\"\n");
And it did what I intended to do :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get position of the `=` and `\n` using [String.indexOf(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) and then replace the string between `=` and `\n` using, for example, [replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Btw - `some_property=(.+)` (and replacing $1) wouldn't be okay? :)